# ibuffer: how to automatically create groups per project

Tags: ibuffer, projectile

I'd like to group my buffer list in ibuffer by project. Project is meant in the Projectile sense of the word.

I don't want to change my Emacs configuration every time I'm working on a new project. Is there a way to achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define filter groups for known projects using something like this:

```
;; Define ibuffer filter groups for each known project
(defun my/define-projectile-filter-groups ()
  (when (boundp 'projectile-known-projects)
    (setq my/project-filter-groups
        (mapcar
         (lambda (it)
           (let ((name (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name it))))
             `(,name (filename . ,(expand-file-name it)))))
         projectile-known-projects))))

;; Set up default ibuffer filter groups
(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
      (list
       (cons "default"
             (append
              (my/define-projectile-filter-groups)
              ;; ... whatever other groups you want, e.g.
              '(("dired" (mode . dired-mode))
                ("erc" (mode . erc-mode)))
              ))))

;; Enable default groups by default
(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
              (lambda ()
                (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")))

;; You probably don't want to see empty project groups
(setq ibuffer-show-empty-filter-groups nil)
```

**Update**

Since I originally wrote this answer, @sanityinc has created a variant of `ibuffer-vc` that creates filter groups by projectile project root. You can find `ibuffer-projectile` on MELPA or on [GitHub](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-projectile).

Comment: This is exaktly what I've been looking for, thanks!

Comment: This could be merged into Projectile.

Comment: Yes, I should submit a pull request to support ibuffer groups. It came up once before but I didn't follow up. :D I'll take a closer look, it might make more sense to do something like ibuffer-vc and build the groups based on current buffers rather than the known project list. But a simple option would be to have projectile define a named filter group from known projects as shown here.

Comment: As @Silex noted in another answer, someone already added ibuffer support earlier this year -- I had missed that. It's a different approach in that it filters ibuffer for the current project only, but looks handy.

Comment: @glucas well but I think the current Ibuffer behaviors in Projectile is redundant with `projectile-switch-buffer`. Ibuffer is meant for managing large amount of buffers, and that's why it has grouping and filtering. I like the current approach that it groups based on known project list, making it more consistent with Projectile.

Comment: @tu-du Yes, I prefer having a way to group by project rather than only filter by project. My simplistic approach of creating a group per known project could be improved by creating groups on the fly based on the open buffers list. That would avoid having lots of empty projects; and would also work when you create a new project that wasn't known when you first started ibuffer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution @glucas.  I would suggest moving the definition of `ibuffer-saved-filter-groups` inside the `ibuffer-mode-hook` function, since the current code updates the groups only once when Eamcs loads.

Answer (score 5):

> Project is meant in the Projectile sense of the word.

Using Projectile, there is a way to switch to a buffer inside a specific project `C-c p b`

May I suggest [ibuffer-vc](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-vc)? A way to group your buffers by their parent vc root directory.

Comment: `ibuffer-vc` is pretty near to what I'm looking for. But it overwrites my `ibuffer-saved-filter-groups`; is there a way to create the VC groups additionally to my standard groups?

Comment: @ckruse do not know; let me dig please.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/reinh/dotemacs/blob/master/conf/init.org#ido. Specifically the part beginning `nox/ibuffer-apply-filter-groups`.

Answer (score 3):

Using projectile, you can simply type <kbd>C-c p I</kbd> (projectile-ibuffer) and only the buffers for that project will show up in ibuffer.